# Querying Cassandra for node statuses within Java

Tags: java, cassandra, nodetool

I'd like to query Cassandra for the information retrieved with a `nodetool status` command in a Java application. Is this possible or do I have to run nodetool and parse the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in current versions to get that information over cql. There will be a ring state in system_views keyspace in future but in current versions its impossible. You have to either use JMX like nodetool or run nodetool and parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

Some of information is exposed via [cluster metadata](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/metadata/) - you can get `Metadata` object via `Cluster.getMetadata`, then get all hosts via `getAllHosts` and extract [data](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/Host.html), like, is node up or not, what token ranges it owns, etc.